# Open source alternative to the Credential Management functionality of Okta, OneLogin and Bitium?

Tags: single-sign-on, enterprise, browser-plugin, okta

Here is the use case - my parents are not good at remembering passwords. I want to use a software that they can simply log in with one credential and they have access with all their web apps and preferably native apps.

I know there are all kinds of password management software out there such as One Password or Last password, but the thing is, my parents are not good at computer AT ALL. When I am at home, I help them logging in and registering accounts. Now I am living abroad, they don't have anyone that can help them and I want to set something up for them which they can use right away. I tried Okta, One Login and Bitium which allow me to put the credentials of all their apps in, and then they can access their webapps very easily. However, those three apps are enterprise software and they are pretty expensive.

All my parents need is a webapp with bookmark + password store functionality. I am wondering is there any alternative free/open-source projects out there? If not, what are some starting points to achieve this functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I higtly recommend [YithLibrary](https://www.yithlibrary.com/)
The source code is here:

- https://github.com/lorenzogil/yith-library-server
- https://github.com/ablanco/yith-library-web-client
- https://github.com/lorenzogil/yith-library-mobile-client

Some extra info:
https://blog.openshift.com/yith-library-lorenzo-gil-sanchez-app-gallery/

Comment: This is awesome. Although it doesn't solve my problem 100%, it's a good starting point. Thanks!